# Security scanner working procedure?

Tags: security-review, security-scanner

I have submitted my org a week before in Security scanner and it was in queue for a long time. After which I updated our apex codes in the submitted org. So I would like to know whether updated code will be scanned or the existing code which was submitted during submitted date?

Comment: are you talking about checkmarx scan? If yes, then in it we submit particular org for scan so if you haven't received response from checkmarx it is possible that your updated code would be scanned. If you are talking about security scan which salesforce does in that case you have to again submit the updated code.

Comment: I'm not sure if they'll respond, but I've sent a message directly to CheckMarx regarding this. I don't know if anyone in the community would actually be able to answer this, but it's a good question.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I submitted in CheckMarx scan. I will let you know after getting the results of the scan

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for sending message to CheckMarx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a call with **CheckMarx** customer care.

He mentioned that if the submitted org is in queue then it is not yet scanned. So on the time of scanning whatever code available in the org will be scanned regardless of queue.

ie)***Checkmarx report contains the time it started scan. That is the version scanned at that moment.***

Comment: Checkmarx report contains the time it started scan. That is the version scanned at that moment.

Comment: @Ashwani updated in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For race conditions such as these, since loose code is scanned and not a package version, I would recommend running another scan if you think the code changes are large enough to warrant it. My guess is that the old version of your code got scanned, but there just isn't a way to tell.